# Django REST Framework filter by Foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

First of all, please consider that I'm very new in `Django` so I'm not really sure about what I'm looking for.

I have a model called `Product`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
   ...
```

One `Product` can have several variants so I created another model called `ProductVariant` which has a `ForeignKey` to `Product`.

```
class ProductVariant(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product,
                            verbose_name='Produkt',
                            related_name='productvariants',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
...
```

I want to return only the Products that have Variants but I don't know how to access that information from the `Product Filter` or `Product Serializer`, since the `ForeignKey` is on the `ProductVariant` model.

Any ideas? I know this is basic Django but I'm completely new, any help would be really appreciated.

This is my `Product Filter:`

```
class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['id', 'name']
```

The `Product Serializer`:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = Product
       fields = ('id', 'name')
```

The `Product ViewSet`:

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Product.objects.all()
   filterset_class = ProductFilter
   serializer_class = ProductSerializer
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control what goes into the ModelView response by changing the `queryset` field. If you want to see only those `Product`s that have a variant, try filtering for those, that have a variant with a non-`None` `name` field (if there is one, it will have a value).

```py
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Product.objects.filter(productvariants__name__isnull=False).distinct()
   filterset_class = ProductFilter
   serializer_class = ProductSerializer
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

I have added a `.distinct()` call so that each `Product` only appears once.